# Let $L,F$ be extensions over the field $K$ and $L,F$ are contained in a common field (cont)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L,F$ be extensions over the field $K$ and $L,F$ are contained in a common field. Prove that $\left[LF:K\right]\leq\left[L:K\right]\left[F:K\right]$

Help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a basis for $L$ over $K$ and a basis for $F$ over $K$, and multiply them together to get a set that spans $LF$ over $K$

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me? Please

Comment: If $L,F$ are infinite extensions, can we take a basic?

Comment: Help me. Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $[L:K] = n < \infty$, and hence
$$
L = K[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots , \alpha_n] \Rightarrow LF = F[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots , \alpha_n]
$$
and so $[LF:F] \leq [L:K]$. Thus,
$$
[LF:K] = [LF:F][F:K] \leq [L:K][F:K]
$$